# solid model help

Tags: solidify-modifier

I have a 3d meshed model of a building created in agisoft, I would like to add a base and a solid end to the building. Effectively closing off the building.

The 3d mesh is very detailed.

Suggestions on how to do this to a blender newbie would be really appreciated.

Thanks W
[image]

Comment: You need to select the edge loop and press F to fill. But do you plan to 3D print? In that case you need to make sure that your object is manifold, that you don't have intersecting faces, floating edges, etc

Comment: Thanks @moonboots, so I need to do this for the base as well.

Comment: If this is for 3D print it needs to be a closed mesh, so yes you need to do it for the base as well

Comment: Okay thanks, how do ensure I get just the edge when selecting?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to visually control that it is correctly selected

Comment: is there a way in blender to create a solid box, then subtract the mesh from the solid box? Leaving a solid that's edged by the mesh?

Comment: You could use the knife tool, K to activate, A to cut orthogonally, C to cut through, once you've cut keep the new edge loop selected, press V to rip off, select the part you want to delete with L, delete with X?